# Using VST.NET how do I get the current transport time of the DAW that hosts it?

Tags: c#, vst

I'm using https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/vst.net to create a small plugin that will draw a cute animation relative to the current transport time of the DAW (playback in arrangement view). I'm not able to get that data. Ideally, to get all data from VstTimeInfo struct.

I have tried to use: `Host.GetInstance<IVstHostCommands20>().GetTimeInfo(VstTimeInfoFlags.TransportPlaying);`

But all values of the returned *VstTimeInfo* are 0. What I'm doing wrong or what do I need to do?

//. Edit. It works in FL Studio, but not Bitwig. Which is the target DAW...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what Time-info is supported is dependent on the Host/DAW - as you have seen. You can check the Flags property of the return value. The host *should* specify what it supports (and what is filled in the other properties) in that field.

You can also put in a request at the Host/DAW in question for it to support more options...

[Author of VST.NET]